# Recyclerview remove only first items

Tags: android

Anybody know how to remove checked items in Recycerview.I have removed only first items.

My code is

```
    public void delete(View view)
    {
         for (int i=0;i<vector.size();i++)
        {
            if (vector.get(i).isSelected())
            {
                vector.remove(i);

            }
        }
            recAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: Here you are removing all selected items, not the first one..

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add `boolean` `isFirst` to the code .

Try this in your code .

```
private boolean isFirst = true;

public void delete(View view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        if (vector.get(i).isSelected()) {
            if (isFirst) {
                vector.remove(i);
                isFirst = false;
            }
        }
    }
    recAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public void delete(View view)
{
     for (int i=0;i<vector.size();i++)
    {
        if (vector.get(i).isSelected())
        {
            vector.remove(0);

        }
    }
        recAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```